# How to make a flat terrain with the terrain absorber in Rftools

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I tried to place a terrain absorber on a flat area that has 20x20 blocks and nothing else, it is completely flat, but I just get terrain normal not flat. How do I get a flat terrain essence?

Answer (score 1):

Check JEI/NEI (whatever), it may be a craftable dimlet. It's possible that if not, it may have been disabled by the mod author.

Your other option is create whatever dimension (even just a random) and search through the dimlet huts in the dimension for a dimlet you want.